# Find all the functions $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$, such that $f\left(x+2^y\right)=f(x)+2^{f(y)}$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Find all the functions $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$, such that for any $x \in \mathbb R$ and  $y \in \mathbb R$ 
>   $$f\left(x+2^y\right)=f(x)+2^{f(y)}$$

*I have no idea how to solve this problem.*

Comment: I have not yet fully solved the problem, but I have a hint. Clearly the function is increasing. Now try to show that it must be continuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suggestion: I don't know how either, but look at what $x = y = 0$ tells you: $f(1) = f(0) + 2^{f(0)}$. If we let $A = 2^{f(0)}$ for the moment, then by plugging in some other values for $x$ (holding $y$ at 0) we get
$$
f(2) = f(1+1) = f(1) + A\\
f(3) = f(2+1) = f(2) + A = f(1) + 2A \\
f(n + 1) = f(n) + A = \ldots = f(1) + (n-1) A
$$

So on the integers at least, you have something affine.

**Post-comment additions**:

Following @JLoreaux's comment, this actually holds for all integers. And Rupert's comment gives us that $f$ is increasing. So if we can just prove continuity, we'll be done: pick $f(0)$, and the rest follows.

For continuity: Look at $f(x+h) - f(x)$ as $h \to 0+$. Write $y = \log_2 h$, so that $h = 2^y$, and as $h \to 0$, $y \to -\infty$. Then we get
$$
f(x+h) - f(x) = 2^{f(\log_2 h)} = 2^{f(y)}.
$$
with $y \to -\infty$. Now for $y$ a dyadic rational, the function is affine, and since the affine slope is positive, on the dyadic rationals, 
$f(y) -> -\infty$. But since $f$ is increasing, we actually can extend this to say that $f(y) \to -\infty$ on the reals as well.

Hence
$$
\lim_{h \to 0+} f(x+h) - f(x) = 0.
$$

So the function is right-continuous at every point.

So this leaves only left-continuity. For that, at present, I have no insight. But maybe "affine on the dyadic rationals and right continuous" actually implies continuity on the reals. It sure *seems* likely, but my analysis skills are way out of date.

Comment: John, by choosing y to be a negative integer and applying induction, you can extend this to show that f is affine on the dyadic rationals.

Comment: See further post-comment additions; I think we're almost done.

Comment: The left-continuity is also easy. Note $f(x - h) = f(x) - 2^{f(\log_2(h))}$ for $h > 0$.

Comment: For the continuity maybe that helps: choose $y=n$ and $x=x_0 \in \Bbb R$ then we get $f(x_0+2^n)=f(x_0)+A.2^{nA}$. Take $n \rightarrow -\infty$ then the sequence $x_0+2^n $ goes to $x_0$ and $f(x_0+2^n)$ goes to $f(x_0)$. Right?

Comment: Thanks, @ArnaldoNascimento and Dominik for filling in those gaps -- I think both approaches work. The one thing I missed was that $f(0) = 0$, as in Sangchul Lee's answer.

Answer (score 12):

> **Lemma 1.** $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.

*Proof.* Notice that

$$f(2) = f(0 + 2^1) = f(0) + 2^{f(1)}.$$

On the other hand, applying $f(x+1) = f(x + 2^0) = f(x) + 2^{f(0)}$ twice shows that

$$f(2) = f(0) + 2\cdot 2^{f(0)} = f(0) + 2^{1+f(0)}.$$

Comparing both identities yield $f(1) = f(0) + 1$. Then comparing this with $f(1) = f(0) + 2^{f(0)}$, we find that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ as desired.

> **Lemma 2.** $f(2^x) = 2^{f(x)}$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$. In particular, $f(x) > 0$ if $x > 0$.

*Proof.* $f(2^x) = f(0 + 2^x) = f(0) + 2^{f(x)} = 2^{f(x)}$ by Lemma 1.

> **Lemma 3.** $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$.

*Proof.* In view of Lemma 1, it suffices to assume that $x > 0$. Then $x = 2^y$ for some $y \in \Bbb{R}$. Then

$$ 0 = f(0) = f(-x + 2^y) = f(-x) + 2^{f(y)} = f(-x) + f(2^y) = f(-x) + f(x). $$

> **Lemma 4.** $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$.

*Proof.* By Lemma 1, it suffices to show this for $y \neq 0$. If $y > 0$, we have

$$ f(x+y) = f(x) + 2^{f(\log_2 y)} = f(x) + f(y). $$

If $y < 0$, then the previous step and Lemma 3 shows that

$$ f(x+y) = -f(-x+(-y)) = -f(-x) - f(-y) = f(x) + f(y). $$

> **Proposition.** $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$.

(We can appeal to the general theory of Cauchy functional equation, but let me give a self-contained proof for this specific problem.)

*Proof.* By the mathematical induction together with Lemma 4, $f(nx) = nf(x)$ for all $n \in \Bbb{Z}_{>0}$ and $x \in \Bbb{R}$. By Lemma 3, this extends to all of $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. Then for any rational number $r = p/q$ with $p, q$ integers and $q > 0$,

$$ qf(r) = f(qr) = f(p) = pf(1) = p $$

and thus $f(r) = r$. Now using Lemma 2, we know that $f$ is increasing. Fix $x \in \Bbb{R}$ and choose two sequences of rational numbers $(l_n)$ and $(u_n)$ such that $l_n \uparrow x$ and $u_n \downarrow x$. Then taking limit to the inequality

$$l_n = f(l_n) \leq f(x) \leq f(u_n) = u_n $$

shows that $f(x) = x$.